# How to interact with radiobuttons in pdf form using pypdf2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

Till now i have attempted using the `update_page_form_field_values` method but it has not worked for radiobuttons, I used `get_fields` on an already filled pdf the dictionary had `'/V': '/Never#20attended#20college#20and#20first#20year#20undergraduate'` which is spaces replaced by #20 and text infront of the option.

```
'Q29_gradelevel[0]': {'/FT': '/Btn',
  '/Parent': {'/Kids': [IndirectObject(765, 0),
    IndirectObject(770, 0),
    IndirectObject(758, 0),
    IndirectObject(1899, 0),
    IndirectObject(1900, 0),
    IndirectObject(1901, 0),
    IndirectObject(1902, 0),
    IndirectObject(1903, 0),
    IndirectObject(1904, 0),
    IndirectObject(1905, 0),
    IndirectObject(1906, 0),
    IndirectObject(908, 0),
    IndirectObject(917, 0),
    IndirectObject(912, 0),
    IndirectObject(914, 0),
    IndirectObject(905, 0),
    IndirectObject(901, 0),
    IndirectObject(911, 0)],
   '/Parent': {'/Kids': [IndirectObject(1866, 0),
     IndirectObject(1867, 0),
     IndirectObject(1868, 0),
     IndirectObject(1869, 0),
     IndirectObject(1870, 0),
     IndirectObject(1871, 0)],
    '/T': 'topmostSubform[0]'},
   '/T': 'Page4[0]'},
  '/Kids': [IndirectObject(762, 0),
   IndirectObject(774, 0),
   IndirectObject(781, 0),
   IndirectObject(775, 0),
   IndirectObject(776, 0),
   IndirectObject(792, 0),
   IndirectObject(795, 0),
   IndirectObject(800, 0)],
  '/T': 'Q29_gradelevel[0]',
  '/TU': 'Question 29: What will your college grade level be when you begin the 2022-2023 school year?',
  '/Ff': 49152,
  '/V': '/Never#20attended#20college#20and#20first#20year#20undergraduate'},
```

Comment: @KJ I have updated it :)

Comment: the output I have pasted is from a pdf which i filled and saved

form had various options like "Never attended college and 1st year undergraduate"
"Attended college before and 1st year undergraduate"
"2nd year undergraduate/sophomore" 
and more for "Q29_gradelevel[0]"

Comment: PyPDF2 does not support FDF yet. PRs are welcome